# Colouring terminal output in 14.04 like in 16.04

Tags: 14.04, command-line, 16.04, gnome-terminal, colors

I've turned my dual-boot into a triple-boot and I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 as well as Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.

I've noticed that the terminal output of 14.04 is only coloured for directories.  In 16.04 I had much more output that was already coloured that made things easy.

For examples, here is the output of `dmesg` in 16.04:

[image: 16.04]

As you can see above, lots of things are coloured to make it easier to skim through.  I purposely generated an error here to show how errors are automatically coloured red to make them easier to spot.

Below is the output of `dmesg` in 14.04:

[image: 14.04]

As you can see, it's much harder to read.

I've tried setting terminal themes and such, but no automatic colouring.  I've also read about a file `/etc/terminal-colors.d` but I don't have this in 16.04.

How can I export the colouring settings from 16.04 and import them into 14.04?  Or is this simply a matter of different versions of the terminal?  I'm considering permanently switching over to Ubuntu Gnome 14.04, there's just a few of these things I'd like to update first.

I've already tried uncommenting the `force_color_prompt=yes` in `.bashrc` and it didn't change anything.

Comment: This may help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/95842/how-can-i-see-dmesg-output-as-it-changes

Comment: @ChrisK My question has nothing to do with watching dmesg output, I was just using it as an example.  My question is about the colouring.

Comment: What kind of things are you interested in coloring ? errors ?

Comment: @Serg Thing like my first screenshot.  Timestamps within brackets, program names and yes, errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dmesg` on 16.04 supports colouring output, and on 14.04, it doesn't. Just look at the manpages.

1. [16.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dmesg.1.html):

   ```
   -L, --color[=when]
         Colorize the output.  The optional argument when  can  be  auto,
         never  or  always.  If the when argument is omitted, it defaults
         to auto.  The colors can be disabled, for the  current  built-in
         default see --help output. See also the COLORS section.
   ```
2. [14.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/dmesg.1.html): No such option.

Comment: So my example is a specific `dmesg` version problem and nothing to do with the terminal?  Can `dmesg` be upgraded in 14.04?

Comment: You can try manually installing the package from 16.04, but who knows what problems that might cause. I don't think this will be backported.

Comment: Yep, you were right.  The colouring is definitely `dmesg` itself doing it and not the terminal.  That's unfortunate since it's the first place I go to when there's problems, but this is the correct answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully setting `force_color_prompt=yes` directive in your `.bashrc` file will make it work. The `force_color_prompt=yes` directive is commented by default. Uncomment it, save it and source your .bashrc file to see the changes.

Command for sourcing your `.bashrc` file is

```
cd ~
source .bashrc
```

Comment: I did this previously which I should have mentioned in my question.  It didn't change anything.  I will update my question to state this.